# Is it possible to work android 2.2 application on other android versions (1.5 to 2.1)?

Tags: android

I developed one application based on android 2.2 version.
Is it possible to work that application on other android versions (1.5 to 2.1)?

Comment: Are you using any 2.2 SDK specific stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the functionality of the platform used in the application. If you have used any of the features of the 2.2, then you cannot. You can see which features are supported by checking the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) (just an example). On the top right, you get a drop down list which you can filter for the API versions.

---

Easiest way to find out if it is working is to change minimum required version to LEVEL 3 of API (1.5) and then change the class path (sometimes it does it itself) and then compile. It will tell you if it works.

Comment: I developed application based on contact API. I written the code based on Android 2.2. Is this functionality working on other android versions?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible unless you use specific things like programm installation on sd-card or a2dm features which are available only in FroYo.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware than in 1.5 multi-size screens are not manage.
I'm not sure about the effect of density.