# How to develop android app for more application level (more android versions)?

Tags: android

I want to develop some android applications for many android versions: >1.5 . How can I do this?

Comment: Did this really need to be asked on here?

Comment: *Related:* [Is it possible to work android 2.2 application on other android versions (1.5 to 2.1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439362/is-it-possible-to-work-android-2-2-application-on-other-android-versions-1-5-to)

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#DeclaringRequirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just develop your application for the lowest version you want it to be compatible with, it will be compatible with further versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Support Libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)